# How to sum all shown transactions in rails?

Tags: javascript, sql, ruby-on-rails-4, model, view

I am making a budgeting app that allows users to add money transactions (purchases) to keep track of their spending. The transaction model has 3 fields: date, description and amount. In the transactions index view I have a filter to adjust the range of dates to display transactions for. How do I display a total amount  (sum) of all the transactions currently shown on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
Transaction.where("date between d1 and d2").pluck(:amount).sum
```